# Jquery data table's scrolling and header not align

Tags: jquery, datatable, vertical-alignment, vertical-scrolling

My datatable scroll bar and datatable's alignment not the same as per needed

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#tblServer').DataTable({
    orderCellsTop: false,
    fixedHeader: true,
    "ordering": false,
    "lengthChange": false,        
    "sDom": 'Rfrtlip',
    "bPaginate": false,
    responsive: true,
    "autoWidth": false,
    "scrollY": "100px",
    "scrollCollapse": true,
    "paging": false,                    
  });
});
```

Please find code below
[DataTable Example](http://jsfiddle.net/shivani_pandya/172dmxka/14/)

[image: issue]

Comment: Not really clear what you you're asking.  From the jsfiddle and screenshot, they already align neatly.

Comment: That's correct. The table header is fixed so the scrollbar is just for the table body..

Comment: I know that is correct , but i need to implement scroll bar align with header column

Comment: Check this fiddle, you just need to add correct .css files http://jsfiddle.net/172dmxka/15/

Comment: this is not working because , I need border for table in design

Comment: Then you need to change from fixed header to normal table, with scroll container..

Comment: I need fix header

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is functionality , not an issue !!

Answer (score -2):

add below **css** in your **style**. not a great fix but it looks better than leaving it blank.

```
.dataTables_scrollHead{
  overflow-y:scroll;
}
```

Comment: header border toolbar no need to implement over there , it will not achieve your design aspect

Comment: you have two options, 1) get scrollbar for header as i suggested  OR 2) extend the last th element to cover the remaining header area, you might need JQuery/Javascript here.